# default check in radiobutton list in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, radiobuttonlist

i am passing list of values in radiobutton ( 5 values). but i want one among them should be selected/checked by default. How can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set the view model property to the required value. Example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel { Value = "No" };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and in the view:

```
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Value, "Yes", new { id = "yes" }) %> Yes
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Value, "No", new { id = "no" }) %> No
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Value, "Maybe", new { id = "maybe" }) %> Maybe
```

which will select the `No` button.